# AutoIt _IEAttach - No match in IE mode

Tags: internet-explorer, webdriver, autoit

To begin, i open a webpage that then reloads in IE mode through Edge. Once loaded i want to click on the Login button with the innertext "Login".

But autoit says that it can't pick up the window title, the url or anything else that i have tried referencing to that window. Below is my code, using site as an example. I have used the window tool from autoit to find other information. Have tried looking at the documents for _IEAttach. Tried, "url", "title", also "Winlist", "HWD" but still not able to attach the IE to the webpage.
I've tried running it through microsoft edge then having the webpage load automatically in IE(i've checked it so that it will always load in IE combatility mode as it's required to run the webpage) and i've tried loading it through internet explorer as well. I have tried using Selenium and webdriver, but that doesn't work for me either. So i prefer using auto it.

Problem: IEAttach - No match. Can someone assist?

Also, i once received this error-

> C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\Include\IE.au3" (2111) : ==> The requested action with this object has failed.: Return

> SetError($_IESTATUS_Success, 0, HWnd($oObject.HWnd())) Return

> SetError($_IESTATUS_Success, 0, HWnd($oObject^ ERROR

> Exit code: 1

```
#include <IE.au3>

; Navigate to the URL in Internet Explorer
Run("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe " & "https://site1.com")

Local $oIE = Null
; Wait for the webpage to load and open in IE mode
Do
    $title = "Site1"
    $hWnd = WinGetHandle($title)
    ;ConsoleWrite("Window title: " & $title & ", HWND: " & $hWnd & @CRLF)
    $oIE = _IEAttach($hWnd, "hwnd")
Until IsObj($oIE)

; Wait for the page to finish loading
_IELoadWait($oIE)

; Get all the button elements on the page
Local $oButtons = _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, "button")

; Loop through the buttons to find the one with the Login text
For $oButton In $oButtons
    If StringStripWS(_IEPropertyGet($oButton, "innerText"), 8) = "Login" Then
        ; Click the Login button
        _IEAction($oButton, "click")
        ExitLoop
    EndIf
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it can be perfectly done by Selenium + IE Driver. Something might have been missed at your last attempt. Here's an example in Python to click a login button with the text "Login":

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

ie_options = webdriver.IeOptions()
ie_options.attach_to_edge_chrome = True
ie_options.edge_executable_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe"

driver = webdriver.Ie(options=ie_options)

driver.get("http://www.site1.com")
elem = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Login')
elem.click()

driver.quit()
```

For more information, you can read [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode?tabs=c-sharp).